# htaccess after removing all .php extensions can't redirect single files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to remove all .php extensions from URL with htaccess but also redirect for example the `example.com/profile.php?user=test` to `example.com/profile/test` the following code will remove all .php extensions, but getting **500 error** because of the single file (profile.php) redirection

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

apache2 log:

```
 Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add this code, it redirects the user paramater to url.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, but still getting that exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects error.

Comment: edit my answer, please check again

Comment: Now in the error log says: `script '/var/www/html/profile.php' not found or unable to stat` but the profile.php is exists in the /var/www/html folder. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with default apache2 configuration. And what about the .php extensions?

Comment: is this the right path?
if not, please change the rewrite base to the right path.

Comment: php is running on your server?

Comment: Of course. I deleted all other files from the folder and now working, but if I go to `example.com/profile/test` then the site wants to read all files from /profile/ like: `profile/css/style.css` but the style.css file in the root/css folder

Comment: the problem with loading css from other path, is another question ;)
but you can try this inside head section: `<base href="http://www.example.com/">`
please mark as answered